# C2380 error while using C# dll in C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a Dll built in C# code and due to some need I want to use it with C++ code.

After a long search I found a solution and created abcd.tlb from my abcd.dll file using RegASM.exe.

After import of this file,

```
#import "D:\\..\\abcd.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

When I build my solution an error occurs,

> error C2380: type(s) preceding 'Accepted_Bills' (constructor with return type, or illegal redefinition of current class-name?)    d:..\abcd.tlh

When I search for this error I came to know that one structure,

```
struct __declspec(uuid("23dbd772-5aa8-3b5a-90a1-b19e4a052166"))
Accepted_Bills
{
    long Denomination;
    __int64 Accepted_Bills;
};
```

have same name as one of its member. Which is not allowed in C++. I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile this.

Can anyone please help me to remove this error. Thanx a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to change the declaration on the managed side of the interface. Change the name of either the struct or the field.

If you don't want to do that, you'll need to make the change in your C++ code. For example:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("23dbd772-5aa8-3b5a-90a1-b19e4a052166"))
Accepted_Bills
{
    long Denomination;
    __int64 _Accepted_Bills;
};
```

You'll need to stop automatically generating the header file every time you build and switch to manual generation.

It seems to me that, since you control both sides of the interface, changing the C# code is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanx David !! But This is the structure generated automatically in .tlh file while importing "abcd.tlb". I cannot change the name of variable, as .tlh file is generated by compiler every time I run my solution.

Comment: Then you'll have to stop automatically generating it.

Comment: Can you please help how to stop that. I already tried to find solution this way. But unable to find any till now.

Comment: Stop using `#import` and instead use #include on the generated header file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the Accepted_Bills type?

[You can tell VS to exclude it from your inport.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wfsht8h.aspx)

```
#import "D:\\..\\abcd.tlb" raw_interfaces_only exclude("Accepted_Bills")
```

---

Try to experiment with the other import options e.g. `high_method_prefix("Prefix")` or maybe `auto_rename` or `rename(...)`

Comment: Yes I need that structure. please tell me some other solutions.